# Text is not visible in IE6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-6

I'm doing a site (asp.net mvc2) that should work in IE6 as well.
On a page I inject a control as  partial view.

```
<div id="LocationContainer">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("../Shared/EditTemplates/ContactInfoTemplate",  
            new ContextAwareViewModel<ContactInfoViewModel>()
            {
                ProcessStep = ProcessStep.Configure,
                Model = Model.ContactPerson
            }); %>
    </div>
```

It contains following snippet of code:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <%= Html.CheckBox(Model.Model.ContactType + ".IsDTBranch",
                      Model.Model.PersonViewModel.IsTDBranch, 
                      new { @class = "tdBranchChkBox"}) %> 
    <%= Html.Resource("Resources, ThisIsTDBranchLabel") %> 
</div>
```

That gives in the end this html:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <input class="tdBranchChkBox" id="EventContact_IsDTBranch"
        name="EventContact.IsDTBranch" type="checkbox" value="true" />

    Il s'agit d'une succursale de la TD 
</div>
```

After all of this IE6 doesn't render text. But text is there and appears when I start to select area where it should be.

[image: After rendering]

[image: text selecting]

[image: after selecting]

Does anybody know how it can be cured?
Thanks.

Comment: Please close this thead then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:

In this case, a height correction seems to have done the trick. The Holly Hack involved adding the following code to the CSS file:

```
/* Hides from IE5-mac */
div#content 
{
  height: 1%;
}
```

/* End hide from IE5-mac */ /*— Holly Hack for IE 6 Peekaboo bug —*/

The explanation for this code can be found on the John and Holly website.

Taken from here http://www.bpwrap.com/2005/08/the-internet-explorer-6-peekaboo-bug/
Thanks a lot author.